# Flutter Scroll does not work in the slider

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a button, when clicked it exits showdialog which has a slider (slider_pro - package). I get the photo via json.
The photo comes out fine, but horizontal scrolling does not work.
How to put it inside showdialog - slider_pro, and put navigation there. Thank you in advance.
You can see more details in my code, follow the link.
https://github.com/akbarsulaymonov/Slider_ShowDialog/blob/master/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `List<Widget>.generate` and `InkWell` 
code snippet

```
images: List<Widget>.generate(
          data.length,
          (index) => InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondRoute(
                        url: data[index]["url"])),
              );
            },
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: data[index]["url"],
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Map> data = [
    {"url": 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'},
    {"url": 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=10'},
    {"url": 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=11'},
  ];

  void showSimpleCustomDialog(BuildContext context, data) {
    Dialog simpleDialog = Dialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 10.0,
            ),
            height: 150.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                //color:Hexcolor('#205CBE'),
                ),
            child: data.length > 0
                ? Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 150.0,
                    width: 300.0,
                    child: Carousel(
                        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                        autoplay: false,
                        animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                        dotSize: 6.0,
                        dotIncreasedColor: Color(0xFFFF335C),
                        dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
                        dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomCenter,
                        dotVerticalPadding: 10.0,
                        showIndicator: true,
                        indicatorBgPadding: 7.0,
                        images: List<Widget>.generate(
                          data.length,
                          (index) => InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => SecondRoute(
                                        url: data[index]["url"])),
                              );
                            },
                            child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: data[index]["url"],
                                height: 150.0,
                                width: 300,
                                placeholder: (BuildContext context,
                                        String url) =>
                                    Container(
                                        width: 300.0,
                                        height: 150.0,
                                        child: Center(
                                            child:
                                                CircularProgressIndicator()))),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                )
                : Text("Фото недоступна")));

    showDialog(
        context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => simpleDialog);
  }

  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showSimpleCustomDialog(context, data);
              },
              child: Text("click"),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  SecondRoute({this.url});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("$url"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate back to first route when tapped.
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, everything works and how do I put padding in the showdialog itself?

Comment: Do you want to put padding on CachedNetworkImage or Carousel or Container? Do you encounter any error? can you provider reproduce code?